# snakemake: pass input that does not exist (or pass multiple params)

Tags: python, amazon-s3, snakemake

I am trying and struggling mightily to write a snakemake pipeline to download files from an aws s3 instance.
Because the organization and naming of my files on s3 is inconsistent, I do not want to use snakemake's remote options.  Instead, I use a mix of grep and python to enumerate the paths I want on s3, and put them in a text file:

```
#s3paths.txt
s3://path/to/sample1.bam
s3://path/to/sample2.bam
```

In my config file I specify the samples I want to work with:

```
#config.yaml
samplesToDownload: [sample1, sample3, sample18]
```

I want to make a pipeline where the first rule downloads files from s3 who contain a string present in **config['samplesToDownload']**.  A runtime code snippet does this for me:

```
pathsToDownload: [path for path in s3paths.txt if path contains string in samplesToDownload]
```

All this works fine, and I am left with a global variable **pathsToDownload** that looks something like this:

```
pathsToDownload: ['s3://path/to/sample1.bam', 's3://path/to/sample3.bam', 's3://path/to/sample18.bam']
```

Now I try to get snakemake involved and struggle. If I try to put the python variable in inputs, snakemake refuses because the file does not exist locally:

```
rule download_bams_from_s3:
   input: 
      s3Path = pathsToDownload
   output:
      expand(where/I/want/file/{sample}.bam, sample=config['samplesToDownload'])
   shell:
       aws s3 cp {input.s3Path} where/I/want/file/{sample}.bam
```

This fails because **input.s3Path** cannot be found as it is a path on s3, not a local path.  I then try to do the same but with the pathsToDownload as a param:

```
rule download_bams_from_s3:
   params: 
      s3Path = pathsToDownload
   output:
      expand(where/I/want/file/{sample}.bam, sample=config['samplesToDownload'])
   shell:
       aws s3 cp {params.s3Path} where/I/want/file/{sample}.bam
```

This doesn't produce an error, but it produces the wrong type of shell command.  Instead of producing what I want, which is 3 total shell commands:

```
shell: aws s3 cp path/to/sample1 where/I/want/file/sample1.bam
shell: aws s3 cp path/to/sample3 where/I/want/file/sample3.bam
shell: aws s3 cp path/to/sample18 where/I/want/file/sample18.bam
```

it produces one shell command with all three paths:

```
shell: aws s3 cp path/to/sample1 path/to/sample3 path/to/sample18 where/I/want/file/sample1.bam where/I/want/file/sample3.bam where/I/want/file/sample18.bam
```

Even if I were able to properly construct one massive shell command it is not what I want because I want separate shell commands to take advantage of snakemakes parallelization and ability to not redownload the same file if it already exists.
I feel like this use case for snakemake is not a big ask but I have spent hours trying to construct something workable to no avail.  A clean solution is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a dictionary that maps samples to aws paths and use that dictionary to download files one by one. Like:

```
samplesToDownload = [sample1, sample3, sample18]

pathsToDownload = ['s3://path/to/sample1.bam', 's3://path/to/sample3.bam', 's3://path/to/sample18.bam']

samplesToPaths = dict(zip(samplesToDownload, pathsToDownload))

rule all:
    input:
        expand('where/I/want/file/{sample}.bam', sample= samplesToDownload),

rule download_bams_from_s3:
    params:
        s3Path= lambda wc: samplesToPaths[wc.sample],
    output:
        bam='where/I/want/file/{sample}.bam',
    shell:
        r"""
        aws s3 cp {params.s3Path} {output.bam}
        """
```